# Electromagnetism and Energy-Momentum Tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'll begin with the question:

> A plane electromagnetic wave propagating in the z-direction has fields $E = E_0 \hat{x}cos[\omega(t-z)], B = E_0 \hat{y}cos[\omega(t-z)]$.  Find all components of the energy momentum tensor for this wave.

My attempt at a solution:

The energy momentum tensor is given by:

$$T^{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{4\pi}(F^{\mu\alpha}{F^{\nu}}_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu\nu}{F^{\alpha\beta}}F_{\alpha\beta})$$

I know $F^{\mu\alpha}$.  It is 
 $$F^{\mu\alpha} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & -E_x & 0 & 0       \\
E_x & 0 & 0 & B_y       \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0       \\
0 & -B_y & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

Now in order to get ${F^{\nu}}_{\alpha}$ I need to apply the minkowski metric, right?  That is ${F^{\nu}}_{\alpha} = \eta_{\alpha\mu}F^{\mu\nu}$   Where I am using the (+---) form of the metric.  In which case this would leave ${F^{\nu}}_{\alpha} = F^{\mu\alpha}$, since the diagonal in the above matrix is composed of all 0s and therefore the metric has no effect.  Is this correct?  I still have another question about going from ${F^{\alpha\beta}}$ to $F_{\alpha\beta}$, but I would like to make sure I am on the right track first.

Comment: Since the metric is Minkowski, this is not GR.

Comment: Note that $F^{\mu\nu}\ne F^{\nu\mu}$.  Also, the metric does have an effect, even though the diagonal of $F^{\mu\nu}$ is all zeroes.  To see that, do the matrix multiplication.